# how change color menu on section scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, sections

[My website](http://test.oxywebdesign.com)
I use the section page.
My site's menu operates throughout the site and does not depend on any section.
I read most of the scrolls and section,css/javascript/jquery, but unfortunately I could not solve this problem
I do not know how to connect menu on sections pages.
CSS code:

```css
div#maximenuck87 ul.maximenuck li.maximenuck.level1 > a, div#maximenuck87 ul.maximenuck li.maximenuck.level1 > span.separator {
    display: block;
    float: none !important;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .dot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 45px !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    }
    .dot>li.active {
    fill: transparent;
    }
    .dot>li {
    top: 50%;
    right: 70px;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    fill: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    }
    .section-1 { 
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
    .section-2 { 
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

HTML code :

```html
    <ul class=" maximenuck">
                <li data-level="1" class="maximenuck item388 first level1 menudr1" style="z-index : 12000;"><a class="maximenuck " href="menuone.html"><span class="titreck">menu one</span></a>
                            
    <div class="container-fluid section1_slider current" data-wall-animate-duration="1.5" data-wall-section-index="1" class="container"> <div class="row"> 

    <div class="custom">
    <section class="section section-1">
    <h1 class="s1h" style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #d4af73;">section1</span></h1>

    </section></div>
     </div> </div></div>
     <div class="container-fluid section2_slider " data-wall-animate-duration="1.5" data-wall-section-index="1" class="container"> <div class="row"> 

    <div class="custom">
    <section class="section section-2">
    <h1 class="s1h" style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #d4af73;">section2</span></h1>

    </section></div>
     </div> </div></div>
     
     <ul class="dot" data-wall-section-nav="" style="z-index: 2;">
        <li data-wall-section-nav-index="1" class="active"></li>
        <li data-wall-section-nav-index="2"></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post any relevant code to show us what you've attempted?

Comment: To be precise, you should provide more info as per the suggestion by @slee423. What do you refer by "section"

Comment: I want to be selected when section one is selected, the color of the item in the menu is white.
And when I go to section two, the color of the item in the menu is black.